# Old cavemen comedy movie in style of Mel Brooks

Tags: identify-this-movie, comedy

I remember watching this movie some time during the **late eighties on VHS** from video rental. While it was dubbed in German, I *think* its original language most likely was either **English** or **Italian** (from what I remember regarding the actors as well as the fact that Italian movies were rather popular back then).

Overall style/comedy was very **reminiscent of Mel Brooks**, it definitely wasn't his *History of the World* though. I also don't think it was *Caveman*.

Regarding the actual plot, there's only one specific sub plot/scene that I remember:

There are **one or two tribes of cavemen**, living in two locations, one being some **kind of bamboo house** (possibly a treehouse?).

An older member of the tribe has some kind of **"accident"**: Some animal (dinosaur?) eats his whole body and the others are only able to **rescue his head**. Since everyone has to do his part, they think about his future, then **put him on the windowsill to act as an alarm clock** for the others.

Comment: I can't see any of the scenes you've mention in [Cavemen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c1AQZopGG44)

Comment: @Richard Exactly, it wasn't *Caveman*. I'm aware of that. However, it would be my first pick, if anyone mentions vague memories of some *"cavemen comedy"*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[When Women Lost Their Tails](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0067639/combined), an Italian cavemen comedy (one of several) from 1972.

> Filli (Senta Berger) and the other cavemen from ["When Women Had Tails"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0066268/combined) are living a carefree, if boring life inside a dinosaur skeleton. But when conman Ham (Lando Buzzanca) introduces them to the concept of currency and economics, their lives fall apart. On top of that, Filli starts to fall in love with Ham...

It's about a war between 2 tribes, and you can see the bit with a disembodied head on a windowsill doubling as an alarm clock below (it's about 10 seconds in):